# NSIndexPath object shows as NSArray object?

Tags: iphone, nsarray, nsindexpath

I am developing one application in that I have declared iVar as NSIndexPath object,but it shows as NSArray object in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. How it shows like that, what is the mistake from my side.
 Please help me.
 Thanks in advance.

Sample Code:

```
//.h file:
NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath;

//.m file:

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

      if([[default1 objectForKey:@"keyToRepeatString"] isEqualToString:[arrayRepeat   objectAtIndex:i]])
        {
            lastIndexPath=indexPath;
            repeatString=[default1 objectForKey:@"keyToRepeatString"];
        }
}

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
int newRow = [indexPath row];
    int oldRow = [lastIndexPath row];
 }

    int oldRow = [lastIndexPath row];........//Here lastIndexPath shows as NSArray obj?
```

Comment: can u please post some example code

Comment: May be, you forget to retain your ivar?

Comment: @Aadhira NSIndexPath in question i wrote mistake.

Comment: it's working fine in simulator @AliaksandrAndrashuk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a memory management problem :

```
lastIndexPath=indexPath
```

That line doesn't tell the indexPath to hang around :)

You will need to put this instead :

```
[lastIndexPath autorelease];
lastIndexPath = [indexPath retain];
```

First it tells any previous lastIndexPath that you are done with it. Then it tells the indexPath not to be dealloced so the memory won't be used for anything else (in your case, an NSArray).

Answer (score 0):

How you declare a pointer has very little to do with what object type the pointer addresses.  Objective-C is very loosely typed, and you can assign, eg, a UIViewController address to an NSString pointer, so long as you obfuscate the assignment so that the very weak type checking in the compiler doesn't complain.

So you can assign an NSArray address to an NSIndexPath pointer and nothing will happen until you try to use the value.

Also, as Aliaksandr suggested, if you fail to retain something that should be retained, the object "behind" the address may be deallocated and then reallocated as something entirely different.  (This problem is especially timing/scenario dependent and may result in code that, eg, works on the emulator but fails on the hardware.)

I had a very much similar problem yesterday (bug in some old code written by someone else that mysteriously started failing).  I ended up having to NSLog the pointer's `description` and `retainCount` at multiple locations through the code to detect under what circumstances it was getting changed and why.  (The problem was a property improperly declared `assign` in another class.)